# Can I assume this data will be normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

If I were to get a sample of random people to solve a Sudoku puzzle, recording the time is takes them to complete it, can I model the range of times as a normal distribution with a mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

If it can't be modelled this way, how else could I do it?

Comment: Well, if they start with the puzzle tomorrow then they cannot be ready with it today, can they? A normal distributed random variable also takes negative values.

Comment: @drhab I'm planning to get users to complete the puzzle on my website, where the time would be instantly recorded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Ben Harris: drhab is right. The normal distribution is unlimited along the $x$-Axis, whereas your time data are limited by $0$ on the left. How about a Poisson Distribution(url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)? This is reasonable, since if I start my puzzle at time $0$, and I am done at time $t\geq0$, then I am also done at every $t+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon\geq 0$.

Comment: I have only studied the binomial and the normal distribution in school. I will  have to research this new method, thank you.

Comment: @BenHarris You were probably going to learn Poisson soon anyway, but it won't be appropriate here anyway. To be honest, none of the distributions you've studied are ideal. If you're approximating the completion time as discrete, something like negative binomial might fit the data well; if not, it's more likely that exponential, gamma, inverse-gamma or lognormal would suit.